# Add Table of Contents to Beamer with beamerfoils

Tags: beamer, slideshow

I want to add a `\tableofcontents` to this `beamer` example. I have tried to follow this [guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), but it seems I am missing some command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerfoils}

\beamertemplatetheoremsnumbered
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}
\title[Title]{Title}
\author{author}
\institute{University of }
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\foilhead{First Frame}
This is on the first frame.

\pagebreak

This is on the second frame, which is a continuation of the first.

\foilhead{Third Frame}

This is on the third frame.

\endfoil
\end{document}
```

What I get is a blank `foil` where the `tableofcontents` should be.

[image: blankfoil]

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no sections or subsections in your docment, hence the ToC is empty.